# How do you specify localhost in an ansible YAML file

Tags: ansible

I am looking to create a inventory YAML file specifying localhost.

I have tried

```yaml
all:
 hosts:
  localhost:
   ansible_connection: local
```

```yaml
all:
 hosts:
  localhost
```

but I get an error about using ssh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the following command `ansible-inventory -i inventory.ini -y --list > inventory.yaml` that converts ini files to yaml. I created an ini file with:

```
localhost ansible_connection=local
```

ran the command and got the following output that worked when I ran my playbook

```
all:
  children:
    ungrouped:
      hosts:
        localhost:
          ansible_connection: local
```